# “Valid until” date for Dubai visa

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, visa-expiration

I hope someone can help me.  I am travelling to Dubai on 21st April 2015 and returning back to SA on 21st May 2015.  I have received a Visa for 30 days.  I am just a bit confused about the "Valid Until" date on my Visa - it is 3 May 2015?  Is this date wrong, as I only leave on 21st May?

Answer (score 3):

OP has declined to respond to a request for clarification so I infer. The standard [tourist visa](http://www.dubaivisa.net/online/duration30days.html) is for 30 days, valid for 58. If “until 3 May” is interpreted (as usual) as the end of that day (ie still valid on 3 May) and the day of issue is not counted, then 3 May is the last day on which that visa is valid on presentation in Dubai. The 30 days limit for the length of stay then starts then. The visa must have been issued today.

In which case the date is **not wrong**.

Answer (score 2):

I was informed by the VFS office that the valid until date indicates the date by which one needs to enter UAE which is 58 days from date of issue of the visa. If the visa applied is for a 30 day tourist visa, then the 30 day period starts from the date of entry and one must leave UAE before the expiry of that period.